# How do I specify specific interface for outbound connection in syslog

Tags: syslog-ng

I have a requirement that I need to separate out my management traffic and product functionality traffic. I have syslog is running in my server and I want syslog to use a specific interface while connecting to syslog server. How is this possible ? Is there any configuration that I can set in syslog-ng conf file ?

Thanks and regards
~S

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce an interface using the `interface()` option in network sources.
This option is available since syslog-ng v3.19.1.

For example: `s_network{ tcp(port(6666) interface("wlp3s0")) };`

Note that the option is meant to be used on the source-side. It may work with destinations as well, but network destinations have their mandatory IP/FQDN address parameter, that should be enough with proper routing.